# Create Postman Delete request with composite key

Tags: c#, .net-core, entity-framework-core, postman, asp.net-core-webapi

I'm working in Postman, I'm a complete beginner and am currently learning database work.
I've created a web API with a small local database and filled it with the data I want, using C# and Entity Framework. All the Postman requests work just as designed, except for the PUT and DELETE ones, where I get error messages (405 on put and 500 on delete). I suspect these are related to the same problem, namely that I'm working with composite keys.

The 500 one on the other hand says that I'm working with a composite key and I'm only entering one value. I have chosen to have composite keys because of a many-to-many relationship between two tables, but how do I enter this into a delete request? Is there a way to format a request URL for this (since I keep getting error 405 Method Not Allowed if I put anything in the body of a delete request)?

I'm sure I'm missing something very obvious here because this doesn't feel like it should be that complicated, but I couldn't find a similar question having been asked.

Edit:

The code is extremely basic, not sure it makes any difference to the problem at all, it looks like this;

```
    {
        public int StudentId { get; set; }
        public int CourseId { get; set; }
        public Student Student { get; set; }
        public Course Course { get; set; }
    }
```

StudentId and CourseId make a composite primary key, and I'm trying delete an object of the class StudentCourse. The suggested/needed request url for this is: /api/StudentCourses/{id} which I don't know how to enter since it's a composite key.

The HttpDelete action looks like this, mind you this is the autogenerated one and I can totally see that it doesn't work because StudentCourses doesn't have any single id to find, as such the FindAsync would never go through regardless because it wouldn't find anything.

That being said, I don't know how to get around that because the action itself only asks for one integer, meaning that Postman recognises that I need more parts of my primary key before it even gets to here.

```
        public async Task<IActionResult> DeleteStudentCourse(int id)
        {
            var studentCourse = await _context.StudentCourses.FindAsync(id);
            if (studentCourse == null)
            {
                return NotFound();
            }

            _context.StudentCourses.Remove(studentCourse);
            await _context.SaveChangesAsync();

            return NoContent();
        }

        private bool StudentCourseExists(int id)
        {
            return _context.StudentCourses.Any(e => e.StudentId == id);
        }
```

Comment: We won't know how to make the changes to your existing code base without seeing your original code. Please post a [mre], and fully explain what needs to be modified.

Comment: Could you post your HttpPut and HttpDelete actions, also the model that is accepting the data and the ajax request?

Comment: Absolutely, I've edited the original post :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming that Id is  a student Id and you are trying to delete all StudentCourse records for this student

```
[Route[("~/api/StudentCourses/DeleteStudentCourse/{id}")]
public async Task<IActionResult> DeleteStudentCourse(int id)
 {
var studentCourses = await _context.StudentCourses.Where(e => e.StudentId == id).ToListAsync();

 if (studentCourses == null || studentCourses.Count==0)
 {
     return NotFound();
 }

 _context.StudentCourses.RemoveRange(studentCourses);
 var result= await _context.SaveChangesAsync();

 if (result> 0) return Ok();

  return BadRequest();
}
```

suggested url

```
.../api/StudentCourses/DeleteStudentCourse/{id}
```